# Go to Home fragment from all other fragments on backpressed

Tags: android

I have three fragments in the MainActivity, i.e **Home**, **Search** and **More**. On backpressed in the **More** and **Search** fragments, I want to go to the Home fragment irrespective of the Backstack.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a navigation component and use a global action to move back to the main fragment.

For more info, have a look at Android's latest documentation on Navigation Components

Comment: How to do that??

Comment: Have a look at Android documentation

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action

Comment: I didn't find the documentation really helpful in my case...If possible can you please elaborate the approach..

Answer (score 0):

You must implement an intention among the fragments within onBackStack (this if you made the FragmentManager correctly), where whenever pressed, the new intent that will be opened will be from Fragment Home, don't forget to clean the previous intent with

```
intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override onbackpress and navigate to home fragment.
Code for overriding backpress from fragment

```
val callback: OnBackPressedCallback =
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Your code here
            }
        }
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, callback)
```